# The integral closure of a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R \subset S$ be a commutative rings. Define the integral closure of $R$ in $S$ by:

The integral closure of $R$ in $S$ is the subring $\operatorname{int}(R)$ of $S$ consisting of all $x \in S$ integral over $R$.

I wanted to verify for myself that $\operatorname{int}(R)$ truly is a subring of $S$. Here is my attempt:

It must be shown that if $x;y \in S$ are integral over $R$, then so are $x+y$ and $xy.$  Form the subring $M=R[x,y] \subset S.$  It is easy to see that $M$ is a  finite $R$-module.  Define $ \varphi, \psi \in \operatorname{End}_R(M)$ by $\varphi(m) = (x+y)m$ and $\psi(m) = (xy)m.$  We can see that both $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are well-defined. Now, by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ each has a (monic) characteristic polynomial, say $f(T)$ and $g(T)$, respectively. So $f(x+y) = 0$ and $g(xy) = 0$, i.e., $x+y$ and $xy$ are integral over $R$.

Please let me know if my proof is sufficient or if there is room for improvement.